# Attempting a vertical line

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting  to insert a vertical line into my code that runs along a certain path of text.

My full code thus far is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <header>
       <title> This Website </title>
       <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   </header>
<body>
<div>
    <section>
      <h1> Test</h1>
       </section>

      <img src="thingvellir.jpg "class="vinstri" height="300" />

<p>
<div class="vert">**Random text that I want my vertical line to follow.**</div>
</p>
   <img src="logo-thing.png" class="haegri" height="100" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color:green;
}

div{
    height:800px;
    width: 1300px;
    border-color:black;
    background-color:#e9b96e;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

h1 {
    margin:auto;
    font-size: 35px;
    }

section
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border:  none;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #888888;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
}

p {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
}

.vinstri {
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
    border:solid black;
}

.vert {
    border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
}
```

Now it's this last attribute that should make the vertical line, but what it does instead of trailing the text, is that it makes a vertical line along the WHOLE ORIGINAL div box (and for some reason adds black border around as well as pushing the text down) as displayed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1HIi.png).

Any ideas on how to fix this one? Thanks.

Comment: I want the line acting as a left border on the text. I was under the assumption that it was what I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DIV rule applies to every DIV, both the one immediately inside `BODY` and your `DIV.vert`. So, the first `DIV` rule in your CSS, applying the full black border, applies to every DIV in your code. I'm assuming you only want this to apply to the top `DIV` instead, rather than to everything.

So give that top `DIV` it's own class, and update that first rule to use the class name.

This way, your `DIV.vert` box, where you want the red left line won't also pick up the additional CSS rules.

Updated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<header>
    <title> This Website </title>
    <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</header>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <section>
        <h1> Test</h1>
    </section>
    <div class="vert">
        <img src="thingvellir.jpg "class="vinstri" height="300" />
    </div>
    <p>
    <div class="vert">**Random text that I want my vertical line to follow.**</div>
    </p>
    <img src="logo-thing.png" class="haegri" height="100" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your CSS:
    body {
        background-color:green;
    }

```
div.main{
    height:800px;
    width: 1300px;
    border-color:black;
    background-color:#e9b96e;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin:auto;
    font-size: 35px;
}

section
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border:  none;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 5px #888888;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
}

p {
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
}

.vinstri {
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
    border:solid black;
}

.vert {
    border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That almost did it. Now it looks like this:

http://i.imgur.com/nEAqcrK.png

But I want the line to be to the right of the image, but to the left of the text.

How do I go about fixing this detail? Thank you.

Comment: The left border is to the left of everything inside that DIV. If you don't want the border to be to the left of the image, than the image cannot be inside the DIV.

Comment: I see. Thank you, Jay. Do you have any ideas to an alternative which will allow me to produce my desired results?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jayharris/fKqL8/ - Remove the `DIV.vert` wrapper around your left image. Within your `.vert` CSS, add a `margin-left` rule, setting it to at least as wide as the image (though more, considering how much space you want between the image and the line).